# Fixing broken code during merge commit or after

Tags: git

Suppose I have a git tree like

```
C - ... A
 \
  ... B
```

and a class that at C looked like

```
class Foo:
    bar = True
```

Somewhere between C and A, `bar` was renamed to `baz`, and somewhere between C and B, new uses of `Foo.bar` were added. Now say I want to merge B into A.
What is best for the git history? Changing any new `Foo.bar` to `Foo.baz` during the merge/in the merge commit, or completing the merge and then renaming any remaining `Foo.bar` to `Foo.baz` in a new commit? The former seems cleaner to me, but I wonder if it's not losing some valuable history information in the tree.

Comment: This is one of those things that gets closed as "opinion-based": there's no clearly correct answer. You might rephrase the question to be more on what are the pluses and minuses of each approach.

Comment: Well, there not being a clearly correct answer is good enough of an answer for me :)

Comment: There's a school of thought that says to never commit broken code. And I'm not sure what kind of valuable history information you are referring to.

Comment: The thought would be, is the merge commit to be treated as any other commit, where any problems resulting during the creation of the commit are resolved in that commit, or not. The history could be something like "`Foo.bar` was removed during this merge," or if there are significant or widespread changes between the two branches, more than just a simple rename of one thing.